# Determine if a sequence exists in a Pandas Series, and return the rows where the sequence is found

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following numpy array stored as a Pandas Series.

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
   1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
   1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
   1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
   1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
   1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

I would like to determine if a certain sequence of '1's are within this array. If so, I would like to get the rows. i.e. Does this array have a sequence of three 1's? Where are they?

I tried looking in the Pandas documentation e.g. *isin()* but those are dealing with a specific element, not a sequence of elements. There didn't seem to be any function to address my need. Was hoping someone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python solution

You can use `itertools.groupby` to get what you want:

```
from itertools import groupby

def oneruns_groupby(arr, n):
    ix = 0
    ixs = []
    for k,g in groupby(arr):
        leng = len(list(g))
        if k and leng == n:
            ixs.append(ix)
        ix += leng
    return ixs

print(oneruns_groupby(arr, 3))
```

So if you want to find the indices of all runs of length `3` (if any), you'd use it like this (I'll call your array `arr`, since I don't want to have to copy and paste the whole huge thing):

```
oneruns_groupby(arr, 3)
```

Output:

```
[2, 17, 41, 71, 87, 100, 172, 265, 359, 376, 380, 410, 442, 495, 523, 551, 557, 609, 620, 627, 633, 637, 661, 710, 752]
```

## Numpy solution

Here's a function that will give you the starting indices of every run of `1` values of a given length `n`:

```
def oneruns_npcomp(arr, n):
    d = np.diff(np.pad(arr, 1, 'constant'))
    start = (d > 0).nonzero()[0]
    runlen = (d < 0).nonzero()[0] - start

    return start[runlen == n]
```

Testing it out:

```
oneruns_npcomp(arr, 3)
```

Output:

```
array([  2,  17,  41,  71,  87, 100, 172, 265, 359, 376, 380, 410, 442,
       495, 523, 551, 557, 609, 620, 627, 633, 637, 661, 710, 752])
```

## Quick and dirty solution

Here's an alternative Numpy solution:

```
def oneruns_qd(arr, n):
    return ((np.diff(np.pad(arr, 1, 'constant'), n) == 0) & (arr[:-n] == 1)).nonzero()
```

It should be noted though that the quick and dirty method finds all runs of `1` values of length `3` *or longer*.

Comment: I ended up using your Python solution. Thank you for taking the time and effort to answer, it is deeply appreciated. 

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [template matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) problem.

If you are only concerned about finding sequences of ones, here is how you can implement a simple solution using `np.correlate`.

This works instead of sum of absolute differences because any other sequence of numbers will result in a correlation value < the template length.

```py
import numpy as np
def find_matching_ones(sequence, length):
  correlated_values = np.correlate(sequence, np.ones((length)), "same")
  return np.where(correlated_values == length)[0] - length//2

def verify_results(sequence, length, indices):
  for idx in indices.tolist():
    reference = sequence[idx:(idx + length)]
    if not np.all(reference == 1):
      print(idx, reference)
      return False
  return True

for n in range(3, 7):
  indices = find_matching_ones(sequence, n)
  if verify_results(sequence, n, indices):
    print("Results matched for length ", n)
  else:
    print("Results did not match for length ", n)
```

This code assumes your array is named `sequence`.